# Ignore parent form tag bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
<form id="update">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <h1>Title</h1>
   </div>
</form>
<form id="insert">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <h1>Title</h1>
   </div>
</form>
</div>
```

How can i ignore the `form` tags between columns and have the same result as the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

An potential solutions should work in all browser especially in IE11 or EI10

Answer (score 0):

You can't. IE doesn't support [`display: contents`](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20contents).

Apply the `col-*` classes to the forms and get rid of the divs entirely instead.

Comment: I know `display:content` but IE i need IE support, i have more div under each form i can have up to 10 divs

Comment: any help i can have more then 1 col-6 div not only one per form?